# Gitolite - how to prohibit fast forward merging?

Tags: git, gitolite

I am trying to adopt a git branching strategy in our office, but it requires that all merges are made without using fast forward. Since we all use different tools to work with git, I would like to know if it's possible to configure Gitolite to prohibit pushes with fast forward merges?
Is it even possible to detect that kind of merge?

Comment: Maybe you could make an alias which includes `--no-ff`? Not sure how you can enforce that across a team though.

Comment: In your comment on LeGEC's answer, you say that regular commits are ok. Then I do not understand what you mean. I suspect that what phd says is true, that it's not possible to detect, but I'd further suggest that what that actually means is that you're not 100% clear what you want to block, because it's not actually definable.

Comment: @Mort I don't want users to merge branches using fast forward, I require them to always create the merge commit to keep this in history. Since there are plenty of tools used and well, simply because we are humans and we make mistakes, I wanted to know if it's possible to detect this and prevent this on gitolite, which we use for repository management.

Comment: Perhaps you mean you don't want them to rebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git config merge.ff false
```

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-mergeff

No, it's not possible to detect because it's not a merge at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could detect that the leading commit pushed to gitolite is a merge commit (e.g : a commit which has at least 2 parents).

You could probably do this in an [`update` hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_code_update_code) on the server side :

- if the branch name (first argument) matches one of your protected branches,
- check if the pushed commit (third argument) has two parents

Comment: I expect the possibility of regular commits, so I can't just reject all non-merge commits. I guess phd's answer still stands. Thanks though, if I was expecting only merges, this would do it.